# Excel - Change poorly formatted energy half hour data into two colums of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

I need to change the format of half hourly date from:

[image]

to

```
Date+Time                Energy(Kwh)
31 Jan 2023 - 00:00       69.9
31 Jan 2023 - 00:30       78.1
```

I have a whole years' worth of data to convert so i can upload it

Thanks in advance.

From

| HH Date | 0:00 | 0:30 | 1:00 | 1:30 | 2:00 | 2:30 | 3:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/01/2023 | 69.9 | 78.1 | 86.6 | 66.6 | 68.3 | 65.7 | 63.4 |
| 30/01/2023 | 31.5 | 31.6 | 31.5 | 31.1 | 31.4 | 31.3 | 31.1 |
| 29/01/2023 | 30.9 | 30.7 | 31.3 | 32.5 | 32.5 | 32.1 | 32.2 |
| 28/01/2023 | 76.8 | 69.7 | 80.5 | 89.2 | 77.1 | 70.7 | 74.3 |
| 27/01/2023 | 95.9 | 83.7 | 80.6 | 76.2 | 95.2 | 94.8 | 86.1 |

To

| Date Time | Energy (KWH) |
| --- | --- |
| 31/01/2023 - 00:00 | 69.9 |
| 31/01/2023 - 00:30 | 78.1 |
| 31/01/2023 - 01:00 | 86.6 |
| 31/01/2023 - 01:30 | 66.6 |
| 31/01/2023 - 02:00 | 68.3 |
| 31/01/2023 - 02:30 | 65.7 |
| 31/01/2023 - 03:00 | 63.4 |
| 30/01/2023 - 00:00 | 31.5 |
| … | … |

Comment: Power Query Unpivot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you might be looking to accomplish this using excel formulas. Therefore assuming no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted, using <kbd>HSTACK( )</kbd> & <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A8</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,B2:H6,
     b,A2:A6,
     c,B1:H1,
     HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(a<>"",TEXT(b,"dd/mm/yyyy")&" - "&TEXT(c,"hh:mm")),3),TOCOL(a)))
```

---

If you need headers then:

```
=LET(
     a,B2:H6,
     b,A2:A6,
     c,B1:H1,
     VSTACK({"Date Time ","Energy (KWH)"},
     HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(a<>"",TEXT(b,"dd/mm/yyyy")&" - "&TEXT(c,"hh:mm")),3),TOCOL(a))))
```

---

As mentioned above in comments by **Sir [P.b.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b)** with <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> it is merely two lines of codes, and just does the required output with more ease.

[image]

---

To perform the task using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, follow the steps:

---

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"HH Date"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"HH Date", type date}}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"HH Date", type text}}, "en-US"),{"HH Date", "Attribute"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" - ", QuoteStyle.None),"Date Time"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Merged Columns",{{"Value", "Energy (KWH)"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Comment: Do you know why the date has cahnged to the american version? And how do i keep it UK date strye please.

Comment: Yes it changed because in my solution I have US date type you need to use UK date types. So what you need to do is instead of `en-US` make it `en-UK` let me know once you are able to fix it ok

Answer (score 0):

Only one parameter input needed. See picture for reference:

```
=LET(
    a, A2:H7,
    b, DROP(TAKE(a, , 1), 1),
    c, DROP(TAKE(a, 1), , 1),
    d, DROP(a, 1, 1),
    VSTACK(
        {"Date Time","Energy (KWH)"},
        HSTACK(TOCOL(TEXT(b, "dd/mm/yyy") & " - " & TEXT(c, "hh:mm")), TOCOL(d))
    )
)
```

[image]